# How to display image of an API via URL with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest

I'm learning Angular and for that I've been developing the Tour of Heroes tutorial from the documentation itself in https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0, but I'm trying to apply some more features like bringing the Hero's image through this [Heroes API](https://superheroapi.com/index.html). I've already managed to build a list with the id and name of these heroes, but I can't find anything related to displaying images from an API. Does anyone have any practical solutions or indicate what exactly I need to study to accomplish this task?

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListaHeroisService {

private readonly API = 'https://superheroapi.com/api/5033128890082701/search/id/'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

list() {
  return this.http.get<Heroi[]>(this.API)
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  )
}

}
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Heroi } from './heroi';
import { ListaHeroisService } from './lista-herois.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  herois!: Heroi[];
  

  constructor(private service: ListaHeroisService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    
 
    this.service.list().subscribe((herois:any)=>{
      this.herois = herois.results;
    })
  }

}
```

heroi.ts

```
export interface Heroi {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    image: string
}
```

Component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let heroi of herois">
  
    <li>{{heroi.image}} - {{heroi.id}} - {{heroi.name}}</li>

</ul>
```

Current results
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you posted, image is not a `string`, is an `object`, change this in your interface:

```js
export interface Heroi {
 id: string,
 name: string,
 image: { url: string }
}
```

```html
<ul *ngFor="let heroi of herois">  
    <li>
       <p>{{ heroi.id }}</p>
       <p>{{ heroi.name }}</p>
       <img  
        *ngIf="heroi.image?.url"
        [src]="heroi.image.url" 
        [alt]="heroi.name">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but just that change still didn't work.
Returned an error error TS2339: Property 'url' does not exist on type 'object'.

Comment: @JulianoEibel I have updated my answer, try adding `?` operator next to `image`

Comment: Still didn't work. Display the same error. :(

Comment: @JulianoEibel, change your interface as I did, your image property is an object, not a string,

Comment: Uhuuul!! Now it worked!! Thank you so much!